# Connecting the login flow between Android/iPhone app and the web

Tags: iphone, android, django, authentication, mobile

When the person opens my app, I want to display a button. The user clicks this button, and it opens a browser (embedded, of course) inside the app, allowing the user to LOGIN through that web page.

Of course, when the person logs in, it only logs in to that **web server**.  The web service now knows that the user is logged in.

As the user uses my mobile app, I need to know if he's logged in or not.  How can I know? There's no way for my app to determine if the user is logged into my web service.

By the way, I am using Django framework for my web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, presumably when your user logs in the server is telling their browser to set a cookie. Why not just capture this cookie and use it to determine if they successfully logged in?

Comment: nevermind. I've decided to just use Webview. It's so much easier.

Comment: Isn't that what you meant by "embedded browser"?